# Issue with rabbitmq

Tags: rabbitmq

I am using rabbitmq for doing image processing.  So here is how my system works.

1. First a user uploads images.The images will be uploaded on the server.
2. Each image needs to be compressed so I created compression queue and I push every image to this queue.
3. In the compression queue the image gets compressed and it is pushed to resize queue.
4. In resize queue the resize happens and it is pushed to s3 upload queue where the upload to amazon s3 server happens.

So here I am using 3 queues where jobs needs to be done one after another.

Sometimes I see that the queue does not consume anything and is stuck like that. I am not able to get proper solution on this.

Please help me in solving this issue.

Comment: It's hard to suggest anything without details on the issue. Please, take a look at [How do I ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) help section for details.

Comment: Are you pushing actual images to the Q, or pushing a small object that points to the filename of the image?  I would never push HUGE binary objects through the queues.

Comment: RabbitMQ can block publishers if there are any [disk or memory alarms](https://www.rabbitmq.com/alarms.html).
If you publish binary objects it can fill memory quickly.